# Avoid div/tables cut when printing

Tags: css, html, cut

I am using the editable invoice template to make the invoice. It looks great on the browser but when a certain number of item is added in the table, the bottom part(as attached in image) becomes cut like that. How do i fix this? I want it to automatically printed to second page when the item is many, and printed on the first page when it fits well.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **tables** you should use `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` Tags. While you should experiment if you need `<tfoot>`. The other two are quite useful. The headline of your table will be repeated on every page which will make your table not look so much cut. `<tfoot>` will also copy the what you define as footer on every page, which may not be desired.

For **divs** you should experiment with `page-break-before` or `page-break-after` **CSS** commands. While these will not help you if you have a page filling div they may help you on smaller ones.

Comment: i've sorted the table. for the div, i tried both page break after and before using the attribute; always. it works but i guess it wont be a one page printed even if the items are fit into 1 page. I tried "avoid" but it did not work. Any idea how can i state a function or codes to make it aware if the item number is more than "X" then go 2nd page?(or vice versa) i am sure i need javascript for that maybe?

Comment: It's a complex issue with printing from css/html. In every browser it may look different, some may print the same content on 2 pages, which is one in another browser. For this matter you may take a look at [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/). 
The best solution in my oppinion is to create pdf. There are some converters that can convert html to pdf. For your question, yes you need Javascript to count the entries. You can also solve it with css but it may not work in every browser.

Comment: THank you for your answer. I think I get the picture on how to do it via javascript. and the normalize.css does help me clean up my code a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this css style for divs:

```
page-break-inside: avoid;
```

Comment: Did you test this? Throws a non-numeric value error on mpdf.php

Comment: I'm certain that I would have.  But remember that this was answered almost 8 years ago.  Browsers have changed since then (and I wasn't using PHP).  If it doesn't work any longer or doesn't work in your scenario, please kindly ignore this answer.